# groovy - for loop returns and EOF error

Tags: groovy

I am new to this forum and I request your help regarding a problem with groovy: I do not understand why the code below returns an EOF error...

```
arUserName=UserName.split(" ");

UserLastName='';

for ( i in 1..arUserName.length -1 )
{
UserLastName=UserLastName + arUserName[i];
}
UserLogin=UserLastName;
UserLogin=UserLogin.toLowerCase();
```

the error returned is the following: Unable to execute groovy function: startup failed: Script225.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found 'UserLogin' @ line 1, column 134. erLastName + arUserName[i]; } UserLogin= ^ 1 error

any idea ?

thanks in advance!
laloune

Answer (score 0):

Pasting your code into the Groovy Console (adding UserName at the top so it works):

```
UserName = 'Tim Yates'

arUserName=UserName.split(" ");

UserLastName='';

for ( i in 1..arUserName.length -1 )
{
UserLastName=UserLastName + arUserName[i];
}
UserLogin=UserLastName;
UserLogin=UserLogin.toLowerCase();
```

Works fine.

As a brief not about code style though, it is usual to have lower-case letters prefixing variable names, and your code could be written in a more Groovy fashion like so:

```
userName = 'Tim Yates'

userLogin = userName.split(" ")    // Split on space
                    .drop( 1 )     // Drop the first element
                    .join()        // Join strings together
                    .toLowerCase() // Convert to lowercase
```

Answer (score 0):

I this the error is caused  because UserName is null or undefined when you are calling split()

in UserName.split(" ")

So arUserName will also be null or undefined.

so please assign some value to UserName and then check if you are getting proper result or not.